# Web Services error on first attempt only

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I've created a Web Service which is accessed by 3 other websites. In 1 instance, after user entered some data and click a submit button it goes off and does it's thing and return true or false.

The problem is when i click submit initially (after a period of inactivity) i get the error

"The remote name could not be resolved: (*mydomainname.goes.here*)"

However, if i clicked the submit button immediately after, it works fine, and will work again until another period of inactivity.

Any suggestions where to begin.

EDIT: New data - I was ready to accept it being a DNS issue at the server site since i tested it from 2 locations (home and office with different ISPs) and the problem seemed consistent, however at the last minute i tried it from my sprint cellular data connection and never has this issue. The web service responds and works well everytime i try it here, regardless of the time that has elapsed between trials. - So i'm doubtful that it's DNS issue again.

Comment: Sounds like the software is working fine; you have a config/network problem. IMHO belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

> The remote name could not be resolved

Something wrong with your DNS/proxy configuration

Comment: why would it work immediately after ? - I've tried from 2 locations, same problem

Comment: DNS configuration error at the server side or the client side ??

Comment: server side; but are you disposing previous connections correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem before when calling web services on Apache from a .NET CF client. Try turning KeepAlive off on your web service client, sounds like a very similar pattern compared with what I was seeing.  The web service call would work on the first try, fail if there was an interval of around 10 seconds between calls, and work every time if there was a 1 second interval. I think it was a problem with the Apache configuration.